# Javascript validation to open javascript alert on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

First off, I don't know much about JS so please be patient with me.
I found this free validation JS and implemented it into my website, however, after a successful validation it doesn't tell you the form has been submitted.
My question is, is it possible to make this validation summon Apprise.js alert on a successful validation? [Apprise](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-v2-The-new-and-improved-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//global vars
var form = $("#ContactForm");
var name = $("#name");
var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
var email = $("#email");
var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
var subject = $("#subject");
var subjectInfo = $("#subjectInfo");
var message = $("#message");

//On blur
name.blur(validateName);
email.blur(validateEmail);
subject.blur(validateSubject);
//On key press
name.keyup(validateName);
subject.keyup(validateSubject);
message.keyup(validateMessage);
//On Submitting
form.submit(function(){
    if(validateName() & validateEmail() & validateSubject() & validateMessage())
        return true
    else
        return false;
});

//validation functions
function validateEmail(){
    //testing regular expression
    var a = $("#email").val();
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    //if it's valid email
    if(filter.test(a)){
        email.removeClass("error");
        emailInfo.text("");
        emailInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
    //if it's NOT valid
    else{
        email.addClass("error");
        emailInfo.text("Please type a valid e-mail address!");
        emailInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
}
function validateName(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(name.val().length < 4){
        name.addClass("error");
        nameInfo.text("Name must be atleast 4 letters (include last name)!");
        nameInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        name.removeClass("error");
        nameInfo.text("");
        nameInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
function validateSubject(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(subject.val().length < 4){
        subject.addClass("error");
        subjectInfo.text("Subject must be atleast 4 characters!");
        subjectInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        subject.removeClass("error");
        subjectInfo.text("");
        subjectInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
function validateMessage(){
    //it's NOT valid
    if(message.val().length < 1){
        message.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //it's valid
    else{           
        message.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can add a prompt dialog box `alert('Your Email has been sent.');` before return true, in form.submit function.